# Using Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors with HAproxy

Tags: security, iframe, subdomain, haproxy, content-security-policy

I want to access content in `www.example.com` from `subdomain1.example.com` and `subdomain2.example.com` I need to whitelist my subdomains in HAproxy.

When I did a quick search on the internet, I only got 71 [results](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1006&q=%22rspadd%20Content-Security-Policy%3A%5C%22&oq=%22rspadd%20Content-Security-Policy%3A%5C%22). (as April 2017)

I'm not sure how to do this in HAproxy config.

`rspadd Content-Security-Policy:\ frame-ancestors subdomain1.example.com subdomain2.example.com` is this correct syntax.

---

Follow up: Do I also need to add below?

`rspadd X-Frame-Options:\ ALLOW-FROM subdomain1.example.com`

`rspadd X-Frame-Options:\ ALLOW-FROM subdomain2.example.com`

Answer (score 4):

Please use `http-response set-header` rather than `rspadd`. The former is part of a newer, more flexible set of commands, and the latter remains primarily for backwards compatibility reasons.

You'd want to create a line that looks something like this:

```
http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors subdomain1.example.com subdomain2.example.com"
```

If you want more arguments for your security policy, add them after a semi-colon (`;`) within the quotation marks.
Example:

```
http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors subdomain1.example.com subdomain2.example.com; script-src 'self'; style-src https://subdomain1.example.com"
```

Depending on context, you may consider using `child-src`on the site calling content, either instead of, or in addition to using `frame-ancestors` on the source being called.

Also keep in mind that for now, Internet Explorer wants a separate header, `X-Content-Security-Policy`which works in pretty much the same way as the "regular" CSP, so you'll likely want to define both these header fields.

`X-Frame-Options` has been obsoleted by CSP, but may still be set for backwards compatibility reasons. AFAIK the `ALLOW-FROM`argument only takes a single source, so that may be a bit limiting depending on the context.